# FullCalendar: Get time by hovering over time slots

Tags: hover, fullcalendar

How do I get the time a time slot actually hovered?

Answer (score 3):

found a solution:

this option in fullcalendar works for me

```
viewDisplay: function( view ) {
      $('.fc-minor').mouseenter(
             function() { $('#myTime').html($(this).children('th').html()); 
      }); 
}
```

Comment: This option has been deprecated in favor of the [viewRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/display/viewRender/) callback. [Source](https://fullcalendar.io/docs1/removed/viewDisplay/)

Comment: @tsuz can u help me to use how to use viewRender? I just tried the answer above then change *viewDisplay* to *viewRender* but not work...

Comment: "This callback will get triggered when the user changes the view, or when any of the date navigation methods are called.

This callback will trigger after the view has been fully rendered, but before events have been rendered (see also: eventAfterAllRender)." @MuhammadDyasYaskur

Answer (score 2):

I'm targeting the "data-date" attribute for each cell with the following in my vue project using the vue component for this library using the latest version 5.8.0 at the time of this comment. You can do something similar with your calendar object when you do a mouseover on it and then use the date value (first converting to your time format using something like moment.js) in a tooltip or displayed anywhere on your page.

```
    <full-calendar
      @click.prevent=""
      :options="calendarOptions"
      ref="calendar"
      @mouseover="getCalendarTimestamp"
    ></full-calendar>

    getCalendarTimestamp(e) {
      if (e.srcElement.attributes[1] && e.srcElement.attributes[1] != undefined
      ) {
        console.log(e.srcElement.attributes[1].value);
      } else {
        console.log("not a date value");
      }
    }
```